# Jenkins - How to pass String from Global config to Job config

Tags: java, jenkins, jenkins-plugins

I am trying to write a plugin where I persist some text in the global config (in a text area) then have that show up in an HTML block under the corresponding job config build step...

Below are the jelly files. I basically want the text under the sampleTextAreaInGlobalConfig text area to go into the sampleFieldInJobConfig block... Is there a way to do this using the getter or constructor of SampleBuilder.java?

**global.jelly**

```
<f:entry title="HTML Note" field="sampleFieldInGlobalConfig"
  description="Place the HTML here that you'd like to see appear in the 'Note from Jenkins Admin' build step">
  <f:textarea name="sampleTextAreaInGlobalConfig"/></f:entry>
```

**config.jelly**

```
<f:entry title="Admin Note" field="sampleFieldInJobConfig"><f:block>
</f:block></f:entry>
```

**SampleBuilder.java** extends Builder

```
private final String sampleFieldInJobConfig;

// Fields in config.jelly must match the parameter names in the "DataBoundConstructor"
@DataBoundConstructor
public SampleBuilder(String sampleFieldInJobConfig) {
    this.sampleFieldInJobConfig= sampleFieldInJobConfig;
}

/**
 * We'll use this from the <tt>config.jelly</tt>.
 */
public String getSampleFieldInJobConfig() {
    return sampleFieldInJobConfig;
}
```

**Update:**

I tried doing ${sampleFieldInGlobalConfig} and $(it.sampleFieldInGlobalConfig) in config.jelly... Didn't work...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Found the answer and it worked.

As this field is part of the BuildStepDescriptor class, you can access it from the jelly script via ${descriptor.getSampleFieldInGlobalConfig()}